# How can I calculate mining rewards from the hashrate?

Tags: mining, block-reward, math

I'm trying to calculate the 24-hour rewards for ethash mining from the numbers at the [WhatToMine JSON API](https://whattomine.com/coins.json).

For example, let’s say I want to calculate the 24-hour mining rewards for 1000 Mh/s ethash: the web GUI says the estimated 24-hour reward is 0.0303 eth,

Meanwhile, the API says:

```
{
"Ethereum": {
      "id": 151,
      "tag": "ETH",
      "algorithm": "Ethash",
      "block_time": "13.7541",
      "block_reward": 2.5419927147638,
      "block_reward24": 2.45464073212852,
      "last_block": 12928877,
      "difficulty": 7045283557960022,
      "difficulty24": 7052581432317500,
      "nethash": 512231520634576,
      "exchange_rate": 0.060053,
      "exchange_rate24": 0.0600458138222849,
      "exchange_rate_vol": 8376.33269589,
      "exchange_rate_curr": "BTC",
      "market_cap": "$276,000,383,779.77",
      "estimated_rewards": "0.00281",
      "estimated_rewards24": "0.00271",
      "btc_revenue": "0.00016849",
      "btc_revenue24": "0.00016253",
      "profitability": 100,
      "profitability24": 100,
      "lagging": false,
      "timestamp": 1627673948
    }
}
```

So how do I get 0.0303 from those numbers? I tried

```
// convert human-readable megahash to raw number of hashes
function MegaHashToHash(i){
    return i*1000000;
}
// convert human-readable megahash-per-second to raw number of hashes-per-24h
function MegaHashTo24h(i){
    return MegaHashToHash(i)*86400; // 86400 = seconds in 24 hours
}
MegaHashTo24h(1000)/(e.difficulty*e.block_reward)
```

And I get 0.00482437394924059, which is a far cry from the web GUI's calculations of 0.0303, so that calculation must be way off... What's the right way to calculate it?

An interesting observation, doing `(MegaHashTo24h(1000)/(e.difficulty))*e.block_reward` gives me 0.031173787222154928, which is much closer to the web GUI's 0.0303, but it's still off... And so far I'm just trying random combinations until I get something close to 0.0303.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could roughly estimate the 24 hr reward as follows:

```
dailyReward = (your_hashrate / api.nethash) * api.block_reward24 * (6*60*24)
```

You need to multiply by `6*60*24` to convert the block reward to the total block rewards of a 24hr period, since a new ETH block is mined every 10 seconds. `block_reward24` is safer to use than `block_reward`, since `block_reward24` is the 24 hr average block reward. `(your_hashrate / api.nethash)` is your probability of mining the next block, so on average your daily income would be that probability multiplied by the total rewards of a 24 hr period.

Comment: thanks! but that number is significantly higher than the web gui's calculations, any idea where the difference comes from? the web gui estimate 0.0303 and `((your_hashrate=1000*1000000) / (api.nethash=512231520634576)) * (api.block_reward24=2.45464073212852) * (6*60*24)` gives me `0.0414033402304427589069035775537486188113689422607421875000000000` (PS that number is from using `IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit` math which is not completely accurate, if i use a high-precision calculator instead i get `0.0414033402304427630106139372676180687679352422387414302835335438...`  which is  )

Comment: @hanshenrik are you sure it's not taking electricity costs into account?

Comment: no, electricity isn't it. however, `every 10 seconds` is just an approximate, for example, the time between block 12934234 and block 12934235 was 7 seconds, not 10 seconds, perhaps the web GUI calculates with higher accuracy with seconds-between-blocks than just `10 seconds between every block` ? (hmm, that doesn't quite feel right either, i suspect the difference is something else)

Comment: is it possible that whattomine considers `time between blocks` to be the `"block_time": "13.7541",` part of the response? ie 13.7 seconds between each block in that response ? instead of 10 seconds?

Comment: @hanshenrik I could help ypu better if I knew what the `estimated_rewards` and `estimated_rewards24` params mean. My calculation gives a very rough estimate, as it assumes a constant block time of 10 seconds and uses the average block time for the last 24 hrs. We need more precise values to reflect a more accurate estimation.

Comment: @hanshenrik Yes, you're right about the block time. I somehow missed it. If we plug this into the calculation, we get a lot more precise result:

`(60*60*24/13.7541)*2.45464073212852*(1000*10^6/512231520634576) = 0.0301 ETH`